# Converting web.config to .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web-config

I need help converting my `web.config` file into a `.htaccess` file.
I'm not very experienced with server rules, because I mostly design and develop websites, so I need some assistance.

Can someone help me to convert the code bellow to `.htaccess`?

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="RewriteRules" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```